# O número de argumentos genéricos fornecidos não é igual à aridade da definição do tipo genérico. Nome do parâmetro: instantiation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, ioc, ninject, automapper

Estou tendo um problema ao desenvolver uma aplicação em Asp.net MVC com IOC, Automapper e todas as outras telas funcionam perfeitamente, só não a de Motoristas. não conseguir identificar o erro, poderiam me ajudar?
Segue as controllers, e as demais classes, caso sejam necessário mais algumas me avisem.

```
    public class MotoristaController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMotoristaAppService _motoristaApp;
        private readonly IEstadoAppService _estadoApp;
        private readonly ICidadeAppService _cidadeApp;
        private readonly IEnderecoAppService _enderecoApp;

        public MotoristaController(
            IMotoristaAppService motoristaApp, 
            IEstadoAppService estadoApp, 
            ICidadeAppService cidadeApp, 
            IEnderecoAppService enderecoApp
            )
        {
            _motoristaApp = motoristaApp;
            _estadoApp = estadoApp;
            _cidadeApp = cidadeApp;
            _enderecoApp = enderecoApp;
        }
        // GET: Motorista
        public ActionResult Index(string pesquisa, int page = 0)
        {
            var motoristaViewModel = _motoristaApp.ObterClientesGrid(page * 5, pesquisa);
            ViewBag.PaginaAtual = page;
            ViewBag.Pesquisa = pesquisa;
            ViewBag.TotalRegistros = _motoristaApp.ObterTotalRegistros(pesquisa);
            return View(motoristaViewModel);
        }

        // GET: Motorista/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(Guid id)
        {
            var motoristaViewModel = _motoristaApp.GetById(id);

            return View(motoristaViewModel);

        }

        // GET: Motorista/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.EstadoId = new SelectList(_estadoApp.GetAll().OrderBy(e => e.Nome), "EstadoId", "Nome");
            ViewBag.CidadeId = new SelectList(_cidadeApp.GetAll().OrderBy(c => c.Nome), "CidadeId", "Nome");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Motorista/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(MotoristaEnderecoViewModel motoristaViewModel)
        {
            ViewBag.EstadoId = new SelectList(_estadoApp.GetAll().OrderBy(e => e.Nome), "EstadoId", "Nome", motoristaViewModel.EstadoId);
            ViewBag.CidadeId = new SelectList(_cidadeApp.GetAll().OrderBy(c => c.Nome), "CidadeId", "Nome", motoristaViewModel.CidadeId);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = _motoristaApp.Add(motoristaViewModel);

                if (!result.IsValid)
                {
                    foreach (var validationAppError in result.Erros)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, validationAppError.Message);
                    }
                    return View(motoristaViewModel);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(motoristaViewModel);
        }

        // GET: Motorista/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
        {
            var motoristaApp = _motoristaApp.GetById(id);

            return View(motoristaApp);
        }

        // POST: Motorista/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(MotoristaViewModel motorista)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _motoristaApp.Update(motorista);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(motorista);
        }

        // GET: Motorista/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(Guid id)
        {
            var motoristaViewModel = _motoristaApp.GetById(id);

            return View(motoristaViewModel);
        }

        // POST: Motorista/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
        {
            var motorista = _motoristaApp.GetById(id);
            _motoristaApp.Remove(motorista);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    public class ClientesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IClienteAppService _clienteApp;
        private readonly IEstadoAppService _estadoApp;
        private readonly ICidadeAppService _cidadeApp;
        private readonly IEnderecoAppService _enderecoApp;

        public ClientesController(
            IClienteAppService clienteApp, 
            IEstadoAppService estadoApp, 
            ICidadeAppService cidadeApp, 
            IEnderecoAppService enderecoApp)
        {
            _clienteApp = clienteApp;
            _estadoApp = estadoApp;
            _cidadeApp = cidadeApp;
            _enderecoApp = enderecoApp;
        }

        // GET: Cliente
        public ViewResult Index(string pesquisa, int page = 0)
        {
            var clienteViewModel = _clienteApp.ObterClientesGrid(page * 5, pesquisa);
            ViewBag.PaginaAtual = page;
            ViewBag.Pesquisa = pesquisa;
            ViewBag.TotalRegistros = _clienteApp.ObterTotalRegistros(pesquisa);


            return View(clienteViewModel);
        }


        // GET: Cliente/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(Guid id)
        {
            var clienteViewModel = _clienteApp.GetById(id);

            return View(clienteViewModel);
        }

        // GET: Cliente/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.EstadoId = new SelectList(_estadoApp.GetAll().OrderBy(e => e.Nome), "EstadoId", "Nome");
            ViewBag.CidadeId = new SelectList(_cidadeApp.GetAll().OrderBy(c => c.Nome), "CidadeId", "Nome");

            return View();
        }

        // POST: Cliente/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ClienteEnderecoViewModel clienteEndereco)
        {
            ViewBag.EstadoId = new SelectList(_estadoApp.GetAll().OrderBy(e => e.Nome), "EstadoId", "Nome", clienteEndereco.EstadoId);
            ViewBag.CidadeId = new SelectList(_cidadeApp.GetAll().OrderBy(c => c.Nome), "CidadeId", "Nome", clienteEndereco.CidadeId);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = _clienteApp.Add(clienteEndereco);

                if (!result.IsValid)
                {
                    foreach (var validationAppError in result.Erros)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, validationAppError.Message);
                    }
                    return View(clienteEndereco);
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(clienteEndereco);
        }

        // GET: Cliente/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
        {
            var clienteViewModel = _clienteApp.GetById(id);

            return View(clienteViewModel);
        }

        // POST: Cliente/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(ClienteViewModel clienteViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _clienteApp.Update(clienteViewModel);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(clienteViewModel);
        }

        // GET: Cliente/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(Guid id)
        {
            var clienteViewModel = _clienteApp.GetById(id);

            return View(clienteViewModel);
        }

        // POST: Cliente/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
        {
            var cliente = _clienteApp.GetById(id);
            _clienteApp.Remove(cliente);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    public interface IMotoristaAppService : IDisposable
    {
        ValidationAppResult Add(MotoristaEnderecoViewModel motoristaViewModel);

        MotoristaViewModel GetById(Guid id);
        IEnumerable<MotoristaViewModel> GetAll();
        void Update(MotoristaViewModel motoristaViewModel);
        void Remove(MotoristaViewModel motoristaViewModel);


        int ObterTotalRegistros(string pesquisa);
        IEnumerable<MotoristaViewModel> ObterClientesGrid(int page, string pesquisa);
    }
}
```

Estou utilizando o Ninject para tratar das dependências:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using ProjetoModelo.Application.Validation;
using ProjetoModelo.Application.ViewModels;

namespace ProjetoModelo.Application.Interfaces
{
    public interface IClienteAppService : IDisposable
    {

        ValidationAppResult Add(ClienteEnderecoViewModel clienteViewModel);
        ClienteViewModel GetById(Guid id);
        IEnumerable<ClienteViewModel> GetAll();


        void Update(ClienteViewModel clienteViewModel);
        void Remove(ClienteViewModel clienteViewModel);
        int ObterTotalRegistros(string pesquisa);
        IEnumerable<ClienteViewModel> ObterClientesGrid(int page, string pesquisa);
    }

public class NinjectModulo : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            // app
            Bind<IClienteAppService>().To<ClienteAppService>();
            Bind<IMotoristaAppService>().To<MotoristaAppService>();
            Bind<IProdutoAppService>().To<ProdutoAppService>();
            Bind<IEnderecoAppService>().To<EnderecoAppService>();
            Bind<IEstadoAppService>().To<EstadoAppService>();
            Bind<ICidadeAppService>().To<CidadeAppService>();
            Bind<IFornecedorAppService>().To<FornecedorAppService>();
            Bind<IVendaAppService>().To<VendaAppService>();

            // service
            Bind(typeof(IServiceBase<>)).To(typeof(ServiceBase<>));
            Bind<IClienteService>().To<ClienteService>();
            Bind<IMotoristaService>().To<MotoristaService>();
            Bind<IProdutoService>().To<ProdutoService>();
            Bind<IEnderecoService>().To<EnderecoService>();
            Bind<IEstadoService>().To<EstadoService>();
            Bind<ICidadeService>().To<CidadeService>();
            Bind<IFornecedorService>().To<FornecedorService>();
            Bind<IVendaService>().To<VendaService>();

            // data repos
            Bind(typeof(IRepositoryBase<>)).To(typeof(RepositoryBase<,>));
            Bind<IClienteRepository>().To<ClienteRepository>();
            Bind<IMotoristaRepository>().To<MotoristaRepository>();
            Bind<IProdutoRepository>().To<ProdutoRepository>();
            Bind<IEnderecoRepository>().To<EnderecoRepository>();
            Bind<IEstadoRepository>().To<EstadoRepository>();
            Bind<ICidadeRepository>().To<CidadeRepository>();
            Bind<IFornecedorRepository>().To<FornecedorRepository>();
            Bind<IVendaRepository>().To<VendaRepository>();

            // data repos read only
            Bind<IClienteReadOnlyRepository>().To<ClienteReadOnlyRepository>();
            Bind<IMotoristaReadOnlyRepository>().To<MotoristaReadOnlyRepository>();
            Bind<IFornecedorReadOnlyRepository>().To<FornecedorReadOnlyRepository>();
            Bind<IVendaReadOnlyRepository>().To<VendaReadOnlyRepository>();
            Bind<IProdutoReadOnlyRepository>().To<ProdutoReadOnlyRepository>();

            // ado repos only
            Bind<IClienteADORepository>().To<ClienteADORepository>();
            Bind<IMotoristaADORepository>().To<MotoristaADORepository>();

            // data configs
            Bind(typeof(IContextManager<>)).To(typeof(ContextManager<>));
            Bind<IDbContext>().To<ProjetoModeloContext>();
            Bind(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>)).To(typeof(UnitOfWork<>));

        }
    }
```

Ao tentar acessar a Action Index, recebo o seguinte erro.

```
Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.

O número de argumentos genéricos fornecidos não é igual à aridade da definição do tipo genérico.
Nome do parâmetro: instantiation

Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código. 

Detalhes da Exceção: System.ArgumentException: O número de argumentos genéricos fornecidos não é igual à aridade da definição do tipo genérico.
Nome do parâmetro: instantiation

Erro de Origem: 

Exceção sem tratamento foi gerada durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. As informações relacionadas à origem e ao local da exceção podem ser identificadas usando-se o rastreamento de pilha de exceção abaixo.

Rastreamento de Pilha: 


[ArgumentException: O número de argumentos genéricos fornecidos não é igual à aridade da definição do tipo genérico.
Nome do parâmetro: instantiation]
   System.RuntimeType.MakeGenericType(Type[] instantiation) +11721331
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetImplementationType(Type service) +59
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) +100
   Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope) +83
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +160
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Resolve>b__f(IBinding binding) +30
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +164
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +164
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) +89
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) +333
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) +152
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target) +17
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +58
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +132
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +77
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) +474
   Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope) +83
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +160
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Resolve>b__f(IBinding binding) +30
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +164
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +164
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) +89
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) +333
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) +152
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target) +17
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +58
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +132
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +77
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) +474
   Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope) +83
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +160
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Resolve>b__f(IBinding binding) +30
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +164
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +164
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) +89
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) +333
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) +152
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target) +17
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +58
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +132
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +77
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) +474
   Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope) +83
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +160
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Resolve>b__f(IBinding binding) +30
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +164
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +164
   Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) +64
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +41

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ProjetoModelo.MVC.Controllers.MotoristaController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +194
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Informações sobre a Versão: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319; Versão do ASP.NET:4.0.30319.34274
```

Repositório:

```
public class MotoristaRepository : RepositoryBase<Motorista, ProjetoModeloContext>, IMotoristaRepository
{
}

public class MotoristaReadOnlyRepository : RepositoryBaseReadOnly, IMotoristaReadOnlyRepository
{

    public Motorista GetById(Guid id)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cn = Connection)
        {
            var sql = @"Select * From Motorista m " +
                      "WHERE m.ClienteId = @sid " +
                      "Select * From EnderecosMotorista em " +
                      "Inner join Endereco e " +
                      "On e.EnderecoId = ec.EnderecoId " +
                      "Inner join Estado s " +
                      "On s.EstadoId = e.EstadoId " +
                      "Inner join Cidade cl " +
                      "On cl.EstadoId = s.EstadoId " +
                      "WHERE em.MotoristaId = @sid";

            cn.Open();

            var multi = cn.QueryMultiple(sql, new { sid = id });
            var motoristas = multi.Read<Motorista>();
            var enderecos = multi.Read<Endereco, Estado, Cidade, Endereco>(
            (ec, e, c) =>
            {
                ec.EstadoId = e.EstadoId;
                ec.MotoristaId = c.CidadeId;
                ec.Estado = e;
                ec.Cidade = c;

                return ec;

            }, "EnderecoId, EstadoId, CidadeId");

            var motorista = motoristas.First();

            foreach (var endereco in enderecos)
            {
                motorista.EnderecoList.Add(endereco);
            }

            return motorista;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.Motorista> GetAll()
    {
        using (IDbConnection cn = Connection)
        {
            cn.Open();

            var sql = @"SELECT * FROM Motorista
                        ORDER BY Nome asc";

            var motorista = cn.Query<Motorista>(sql);

            return motorista;
        }
    }

    public int ObterTotalRegistros(string pesquisa)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cn = Connection)
        {
            cn.Open();

            var sql = @"SELECT COUNT(NOME) 'Total' FROM Motorista
                      WHERE (@nomePesquisa IS NULL OR Nome Like '%' + @nomePesquisa + '%')";

            var total = (int)cn.ExecuteScalar(sql, new { nomePesquisa = pesquisa });

            return total;
        }

    }

    public IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.Motorista> ObterClientesGrid(int page, string pesquisa)
    {
        using (IDbConnection cn = Connection)
        {
            cn.Open();

            var sql = @"SELECT * FROM Motorista
                        WHERE (@nomePesquisa IS NULL OR Nome Like '%' + @nomePesquisa + '%')
                        ORDER BY Nome asc
                        OFFSET @pagina ROWS
                        FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY";

            var motoristas = cn.Query<Motorista>(sql, new { nomePesquisa = pesquisa, pagina = page });

            return motoristas;
        }
    }
}



public class MotoristaADORepository : BaseADORepository, IMotoristaADORepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.Motorista> GetAll()
    {
        var query = "SELECT * FROM Motorista ";
        var motoristasList = new List<Motorista>();

        using (IDataReader reader = Connection.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, query))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var motorista = new Motorista();
                motorista.MotoristaId = Guid.Parse(reader["MotoristaId"].ToString());
                motorista.Nome = reader["Nome"].ToString();

                motoristasList.Add(motorista);
            }
        }
        return motoristasList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Se possível, poste o código com o erro ao invés de fotos. E quando puder, faça um [tour] pelo site, irá ajudar a entender melhor o seu funcionamento.

Comment: Poste também como está o seu IOC (e nos fale qual framework está usando)

Comment: Estou usando o framework  4.6 e não consigo postar a parte que dar erro pq nem entra no código. já aparece a tela de erro direto

Comment: Digo isso mesmo. Poste o erro que você postou como foto em código, fica mais fácil de nós analisarmos.

Comment: Sobre o IOC, me refiro ao que está utilizando para injetar as dependências.  Unity, Castle Windsor, StructureMap,Ninject, etc

Comment: Eu estou utilizando o ninject

Comment: Como você está utilizando Repostitory Pattern, poste as classes MotoristaReadOnolyRepository e MotoristaRepository